# Quadratic possibilities: how to solve this?

Tags: functions, quadratics

Given: $2x^2+kx+2$, under what conditions is it positive definite?

Since it's a quadratic, we take the discriminant $\Delta = k^2 - 16$. For it to be definitive, we need $\Delta \geq 0 $, so we solve it and:

$k \geq -4$ or $k \geq 4$. For +ve x-values, we need that the roots are +ve, so:

$\alpha + \beta = +ve$ and (obviously) $\alpha \beta = +ve$; so: $\frac{-k}{2} \gt 0$ and $\frac{2}{2} > 0$.

What to do after this?

Comment: related http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1427541/for-which-x-%e2%88%88-r-is-the-inequality-x2-5x-6-ge0-true/1427561#1427561

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quadratic function $y=ax^2+bx+c$ is positive definite if $a>0$ and $\Delta <0$ .

Since $a=2>0$ we have that $\Delta=k^2-16$ must be less than zero .

**EDIT :**

$$k^2-16<0$$

$$(k-4)(k+4)<0$$

Now , we have to cases :

1. $(k-4)<0$ and $(k+4)>0$
2. $(k-4)>0$ and $(k+4)<0$

The first case give us solution $k\in(-4,4)$ and the second case give us $k \in \emptyset$ . Hence , final result is union of these two solutions , and therefore $k\in(-4,4)$ .

Comment: That's there, but how do we find the value for $k$ solving the equation?

Comment: @weirdpanda Please see edit .

Comment: Oh, I was expecting a more numeric answer; 'numeric' in the sense a perfect value without the inequalities. Thanks, though! :)

Comment: @weirdpanda You are welcome .